# Multiple statements in single mapper method in MyBatis

Tags: java, mysql, mybatis, ibatis

I have a mapper method to delete all records in a table. But first I need to delete all records from associated junction table. This is what I tried:

```
@Delete("delete from COC_BLOCK_FIELD; delete from COC_BLOCK;")
void deleteBlocks();
```

That seemed reasonable, yet MyBatis throws an exception when processing my mapper:

```
Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
### Error updating database.  Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'delete from COC_BLOCK' at line 1
### The error may involve defaultParameterMap
### The error occurred while setting parameters
### SQL: delete from COC_BLOCK_FIELD; delete from COC_BLOCK;
### Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'delete from COC_BLOCK' at line 1
```

I'm using MyBatis 3.2.6, MySQL 5.5.35-1ubuntu1 and MySQL Connector 5.1.26.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem was that I hadn't set the flag `allowMultiQueries=true` in the JDBC URL.