# execute multiple DB2 statements with MyBatis

Tags: db2, mybatis

i have searched for some posts related to executing multiple SQL statements with Mybatis. but that didnt work. i need to execute multiple DB2 statements in MyBatis . consider i have to run 3 DELETE statements

i have referred below link . in this post they have given example for Mybatis with ORACLE.

[MyBatis executing multiple sql statements in one go, is that possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7174225/mybatis-executing-multiple-sql-statements-in-one-go-is-that-possible)

Query syntax :

```
<delete id="clearTable" parameterType="test">
    DELETE FROM tableA WHERE key = #{key} 

    DELETE FROM tableb WHERE key = #{key} and param = #{param}

    DELETE FROM tablec WHERE key = #{key}  and param = #{param}
<delete>
```

error log :

```
Translating SQLException with SQL state '42601', error code '-199', message [[SQL0199] Keyword DELETE not expected. Valid tokens: OR USE SKIP WAIT WITH.]; SQL was [] for task [
```

#### Error updating database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLException: [SQL0199] Keyword DELETE not expected. Valid tokens: OR USE SKIP WAIT WITH.

#### SQL: DELETE FROM tableA WHERE key = ? DELETE FROM tableb WHERE key = ? and param = ? DELETE FROM tablec WHERE key = ?  and param = ?

#### Cause: java.sql.SQLException: [SQL0199] Keyword DELETE not expected. Valid tokens: OR USE SKIP WAIT WITH.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What have you tried and what is the error?

Comment: Have you tried putting a semicolon (`;`) after each statement?

Comment: @data_henrik yes and it is throwing Semicolon not expected

Answer (score 1):

MyBatis appears to expect a single line for its SQL statements. I don't use MyBatis, but I use DB2.  Try either calling a stored procedure (and pass it the key-values of items to delete), or try an anonymous block.

```
begin atomic
   DELETE FROM tableA WHERE key = 1  ;

   DELETE FROM tableb WHERE key = 2 and param = 1 ;

   DELETE FROM tablec WHERE key = 3  and param = 1 ;
end@
```

The above syntax is valid for DB2 Linux/Unix/Windows current versions (v10.5 or v11.1 ) -  you would replace the literal values with the MyBatis (or whatever) parameter-markers.
One detail is that the syntax above has two delimiters, one is the statement delimiter (which in my example is @), the other is the intra-statement delimiter (which in my example is ;) and DB2 lets you configure both of these delimiters , so you might need to give at least one of those details to DB2 somehow when opening the connection from MyBatis.

Comment: You probably don't need the final delimiter, precisely because MyBatis expects only one statement.

Comment: I have tried this but got some error

Error when using Semicolon :

  DEBUG [SQLErrorCodesFactory] SQL error codes for 'DB2 UDB for AS/400' found
DEBUG [SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator] Translating SQLException with SQL state '42601', error code '-104', message [[SQL0104] Token <END-OF-STATEMENT> was not valid. Valid tokens: :.]; SQL was [] for task [

Comment: ### Error updating database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLException: [SQL0104] Token <END-OF-STATEMENT> was not valid. Valid tokens: :.
### SQL: begin atomic       DELETE FROM tableA WHERE key = 1 ;      DELETE FROM tableb WHERE key = 2 and param = 1 ;     DELETE FROM tablec WHERE key = 3  and param = 1 ;     end@
### Cause: java.sql.SQLException: [SQL0104] Token <END-OF-STATEMENT> was not valid. Valid tokens: :.

Comment: with out semicolon :DEBUG [SQLErrorCodesFactory] SQL error codes for 'DB2 UDB for AS/400' found
DEBUG [SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator] Translating SQLException with SQL state '42601', error code '-199', message [[SQL0199] Keyword DELETE not expected. Valid tokens: OR USE SKIP WAIT WITH.]; SQL was [] for task [
### Error updating database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLException: [SQL0199] Keyword DELETE not expected. Valid tokens: OR USE SKIP WAIT WITH.

Comment: ### SQL: begin atomic       DELETE FROM tableA WHERE key = 1       DELETE FROM tableb WHERE key = 2 and param = 1      DELETE FROM tablec WHERE key = 3  and param = 1      end@
### Cause: java.sql.SQLException: [SQL0199] Keyword DELETE not expected. Valid tokens: OR USE SKIP WAIT WITH.

Comment: My example was for DB2 for Linux/Unix/Windows. You need to find the equivalent syntax for DB2 for i. You may also need to give additional options on the connection string to handle intra-statement delimiters.

Comment: Can you please share any example . i am new to this and i dont have any idea