# mybatis mapper xml execute multiple sql statements in one mapper method

Tags: mybatis

```
<insert id="insert" parameterType="com.youneverwalkalone.cent.web.model.Category" useGeneratedKeys="true" keyProperty="id" keyColumn="id">
        LOCK TABLE t_category WRITE;

        UPDATE t_category SET rgt = rgt + 2 WHERE rgt greater than #{parentNode.lft,jdbcType=BIGINT};
        UPDATE t_category SET lft = lft + 2 WHERE lft greater than  #{parentNode.lft,jdbcType=BIGINT};

        insert into t_category (
        name, lft, rgt,
        time_created, people_created,
        state, type, project)
        values (
        #{record.name,jdbcType=VARCHAR}, #{parentNode.lft,jdbcType=BIGINT}+1, #{parentNode.lft,jdbcType=BIGINT}+2,
        #{record.timeCreated,jdbcType=TIMESTAMP}, #{record.peopleCreated,jdbcType=BIGINT},
        #{record.state,jdbcType=SMALLINT},#{record.type,jdbcType=VARCHAR},#{record.project,jdbcType=VARCHAR});

        UNLOCK TABLES;
    </insert>
```

Above is my code snippet. Call this insert method will get errors.
My question:
1) Does mybatis supourt these grammar--multiple sql in one method?
2) If not support, how to handle this case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MyBatis executing multiple sql statements in one go, is that possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7174225/mybatis-executing-multiple-sql-statements-in-one-go-is-that-possible)

Answer (score 0):

1/ it is actually not related to Mybatis, if JDBC supports it and used DB does (as well as the driver) then yes you can do that with Mybatis.
As noticed by [Gabriele Coletta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7157214/gabriele-coletta) the question [MyBatis executing multiple sql statements in one go, is that possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7174225/mybatis-executing-multiple-sql-statements-in-one-go-is-that-possible) contains the answer.

As you will see, the syntax is different across database types (mysql, ms-sql, oracle)

2/ without object since answer to 1/ is yes.